# Mysql many many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table Employee(employee_id,employee_name), tour(tour_id,tour_name), employee_tour(tour_id, employee_id).
How can I get all employees who join all tour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it..

```
select employee_name from
(SELECT    employee_id, COUNT(*) AS total FROM employee_tour 
        GROUP BY  employee_id) as tb 
inner join employee on tb.id_employee = employee.id_employee
where tb.total = (select count (*) from tour)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use two joins - one on an aggregate query that counts all the tours, and on an aggregate query that counts the number of tours an employee attended, and then compare them:

```
SELECT     e.*
FROM       employee e
JOIN       (SELECT    employee_id, COUNT(*) AS employee_tours
            FROM      employee_tour
            GROUP BY  employee_id) et ON e.employee_id = et.employee_id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS all_tours 
            FROM tour) t
WHERE      employee_tours = all_tours
```

Comment: Thank for help. Do you know, how to insert 2 million records into DB using MySQL, PHP ? Thank u very much.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JOIN statement

```
SELECT e.*, t.*
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN employee_tour et ON et.employee_id = e.employee_id
INNER JOIN tour t ON t.tour_id = et.tour_id
```

Refer to [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked - " How can I get all employees who join all tour"?